# GridView selecting only one page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

In my webforms project I have GridView with 10 rows per page and with pager. If I understand correctly, while databinding the server receives a query for the entire table. I want when the page load, the server is requested only 10 rows to avoid long downloads when a database will be large. And when I'll click on "next" in pager, I want select only next 10 rows. How to realize it? Thank you for your help! (Already see a -1 in my reputation, but I don't care:))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement custom paging,Take a look at these articles

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-paging-with-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net-4-5/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/custom-paging-in-gridview/

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the PageIndexChanging method of the gridview

```
protected void grd_PageIndexChanging(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        grd.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex; 
        BindGrid(); //call the method to load the grid again
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        msgbox(ex.Message);
    }
}
```